# Python multiprocessing Manager dict, access from processes and main

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I try to access an multiprocessing Manager dict from main and processes.
I over write a value and I add to a value.

At the end the dict should be 61 for the value of key 2.
For key 1 it should hold 122 characters since I add two chars per aceess of the dict.

What I get is that the count of chars for key 1 and the value for key 2 always vary.
Sometimes they are 122 and 61 as expected.
The print statements of incre.* though always add up to 61 as they should.

I tried to pass the md1 dict to the processes and the function, result is the same.
Also the same result when I change trd.daemon to False.

Whats am I missing?

Code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def local_func():

    md1[1] += 'DR'
    md1['2'] += 1   
    print('incre func')

def test_func_proc(idd):

    md1[1] += idd
    md1['2'] += 1
    print('incre proc')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    mn = mp.Manager()

    md1 = mn.dict()
    md1[1] = ''
    md1['2'] = 1

    pc = 0
    procs = []

    for x in range(20):

        pc = pc + 1

        idd = str(pc).zfill(2)
        
        trd = mp.Process(target = test_func_proc, args=[idd, ])
        trd.daemon = True
        trd.start()

        procs.append(trd)

        md1[1] += 'TU'
        md1['2'] += 1
        print('incre loop')
        local_func()


    md1[1] += 'CX'
    md1['2'] += 1
    print('incre main')
    

    while True:

        end = True

        for proc in procs:

            if proc.is_alive():
                end = False
        
        if end is True:
            break


    print('md1 %s' % md1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you missing? Operations such as `md1[1] += 'TU'` and `md1['2'] += 1` are not *atomic*. In particular, to execute `md1[1] += 'TU'`, that is, appending to a string, which are immutable in Python, the interpreter has to first get the old string and then create a *new* string which is the concatenation of the old string and `'TU'` and then finally store the result. This can be taking place in parallel in multiple processes and the last one that stores the result could be overlaying the result created in a different process. You therefore need to ensure that once a process starts the fetch-concatenate-store series of operations that no other process in simultaneously carrying out the same operations on the same string (or integer increment operations). And the only way to ensure serializations is with a `Lock`.

Given that your function `test_func_proc` is 100% CPU (except for a debugging print statement), I would suggest that instead of blindly creating 20 processes on a computer that may have fewer CPU cores, you should create a processing pool whose size is limited by the number of CPU cores you actually have. The `Lock`, however, cannot be passed to the worker function as an argument. Instead each process in the pool will see the `Lock` instance as a global variable that has been initialized using a special pool initializer function.

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

def local_func(lock):
    with lock:
        md1[1] += 'DR'
        md1['2'] += 1
    print('incre func')


def init_pool(l):
    global lock
    lock = l

def test_func_proc(md1, idd):
    with lock:
        md1[1] += idd
        md1['2'] += 1
    print('incre proc')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mn = mp.Manager()
    md1 = mn.dict()

    md1[1] = ''
    md1['2'] = 1

    # create the Lock instance
    lock = mp.Lock()

    pc = 0
    # limit size of the pool to the smaller of 20 or the number of CPU cores we have:
    n_processes = min(20, mp.cpu_count())
    # initialize each process in the pool with our lock
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=n_processes, initializer=init_pool, initargs=(lock,))
    for x in range(20):
        pc = pc + 1
        idd = str(pc).zfill(2)
        # We need to explicitly pass md1 as an argument
        # or we could have instead initialized each process in the pool like we did with lock:
        pool.apply_async(test_func_proc, args=(md1, idd))
        # only modify the dictionary entries after acquiring the lock:
        with lock:
            md1[1] += 'TU'
            md1['2'] += 1
        # now the lock has been released
        print('incre loop')
        local_func(lock)

    with lock:
        md1[1] += 'CX'
        md1['2'] += 1
    print('incre main')

    # wait for pool tasks to end:
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    print('md1 %s' % md1)
    print(len(md1[1]))
```

Prints:

```
incre loop
incre func
incre loop
incre func
incre loop
incre func
incre loop
incre func
incre loop
incre func
incre loop
incre func
incre loop
incre func
incre loop
incre func
incre loop
incre func
incre loop
incre func
incre loop
incre func
incre loop
incre func
incre loop
incre func
incre loop
incre func
incre loop
incre func
incre loop
incre func
incre loop
incre func
incre loop
incre func
incre loop
incre func
incre loop
incre func
incre main
incre proc
incre proc
incre proc
incre proc
incre proc
incre proc
incre proc
incre proc
incre proc
incre proc
incre proc
incre proc
incre proc
incre proc
incre proc
incre proc
incre proc
incre proc
incre proc
incre proc
md1 {1: 'TUDRTUDRTUDRTUDRTUDRTUDRTUDRTUDRTUDRTUDRTUDRTUDRTUDRTUDRTUDRTUDRTUDRTUDRTUDRTUDRCX0103040607021012051314151811080919201617', '2': 62}
122
```

**Update**

Read the documentation on [Augmented Assignment Statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements), which says in part (but you should read the entire section):

> With the exception of assigning to tuples and multiple targets in a single statement, the assignment done by augmented assignment statements is handled the same way as normal assignments.

And a demo disassembling Python code to reveal the non-atomicity of the `+=` operator (it takes 4 instructions to carry out `b += 1`):

```
>>> import dis
>>>
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 1
>>>
>>> def foo():
...     a = a + 1
...     b += 1
...
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              4 BINARY_ADD
              6 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  3           8 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
             10 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
             12 INPLACE_ADD
             14 STORE_FAST               1 (b)
             16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             18 RETURN_VALUE
```

**The problem is that 2 processes can both be executing the instructions at 8 through 14 at the same time loading the same value of `b` and incrementing `b` to the same new value. You need to ensure that only one process at a time can be executing the instructions at 8 through 14.**

Comment: I thought the Manager would handle the atomic stuff. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but incrementing is *not* atomic.

Comment: really now? how am I supposed to know that?